# Species-by-year random effects in a GLMM (point count data)

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, mgcv, random-effects

---

### SUMMARY

- **I'm analyzing avian point count data using `glmmTMB`.**
- **I'm trying to estimate year-specific mean abundance for each species.**
- **Models with interactions of fixed terms are not working, I think because
  limited data are split across several factors (species, year, week, site).**
- **I'm wondering if adopting a random-effects parameterization is reasonable
  (shrinking estimates to a realistic range)?**
- **I'm seeking guidance on what the code for that parameterization would look like.**

Any and all recommendations or lessons are *greatly* appreciated! Thank you.

---

### Intro

**The data.**
I'm working on an analysis of a pre-existing database. The data are semi-structured, opportunistic observations of bird species abundance (zero-filled) collected via a stationary point count methodology. So, each species can be recorded at a site during a week of each year, but there are many "missing" observations since it's an opportunistic design. I'm looking for advice on modeling techniques, particularly related to random effects.

**Modeling approach.**
I want to estimate annual abundance for each species through a single model *(akin to a multi-species, dynamic N-mix model, but assuming p = 1)*. Since the data are opportunistic counts, a zero-inflated and negative binomial model should make the most sense. Additionally, there is some pseudo-replication of counts at sites, so I know I need site as a random effect, e.g.: `+ (1|site)`. My understanding is that `mgcv` or `glmmTMB` are my best options for this type of modeling, and I know [Gavin Simpson has mentioned](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/05/04/compare-mgcv-with-glmmtmb/) that `glmmTMB` is likely preferable over `mgcv` when a factor used as a random effect has a large number (100s) of levels (here, 272 sites).

### The issue

I've tried to use interaction effects comprised of fixed terms of `species` and `year` (similar to [the Salamander example](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/biorxiv/suppl/2017/05/01/132753.DC1/132753-2.pdf)) to capture the species-specific annual estimates I'm interested in, but the model runs for hours, only to end up crashing. *(Note: I can only get it to run & converge if I use a gaussian model, but I don't think that's reasonable given the data.)* The terms `week` and `year` are factors (not integers) because I expect both to have non-linearity, which is important. Overall, I think there's not enough data for fully-independent estimates of these terms.

```
m0 <- glmmTMB(count ~ species*year + species*week + (1|site), 
              ziformula = ~ species,
              family = nbinom2,
              data = df)
```

### Current direction

**Random effects.**
I've often been taught that random effects should only be used to try to eliminate effects that are not of interest, but I was digging into resources online and I came across some of [Ben Bolker's writing](https://ms.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/classes/s4c03/notes/GLMM_Bolker_draft5.pdf), which included a discussion of how random effects can have a practical utility beyond stricter definitions. So, I tried switching from interaction effects to various random effect parameterizations, in hopes of allowing levels of species and years to borrow from each other (shrinkage to "population" average).

**However, I've gotten a bit confused along the way and I could use some help from others who have more experience working with this type of data.**

**Starting over.**
I'm trying to restart by going back to the essentials, focusing only on species-year estimation. When I include a simple random effect structure, such as `(1|species) + (1|year)`, the model estimates the same trend for each species, only varying the intercept, whereas I want each species to be able to be totally different. I think I need some sort of crossed or nested structure, but in reading up on those I got a bit confused for this case (i.e., several schools with their own students makes more sense, with lots of examples and explanations!).

**Currently working.**
What I *can* get running is `m1` below, which produces the estimates I want. but I'm not sure if it's justifiable, or if there's something better. I also need something that can include `week` and `site`, too.

```
m1 <- glmmTMB(count ~ (1|species) + (0+species|winter), 
              ziformula = ~ (1|species),
              family = nbinom2,
              data = df)
```

---

#### Data

I added the data to Google Drive, which can be downloaded from [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11pvq-20O4d6z23pmnNuk8Hck2lwhamLS/view?usp=sharing).

#### Data summary

Two representations of the same data:

```
# A tibble: 262,040 × 6
   count species                checklist site  year  week 
   <dbl> <chr>                  <fct>     <fct> <fct> <fct>
 1     0 American Crow          C1262     S174  2020  5    
 2     0 American Goldfinch     C1262     S174  2020  5    
 3     0 American Robin         C1262     S174  2020  5    
 4     0 American Tree Sparrow  C1262     S174  2020  5    
 5     2 Black-capped Chickadee C1262     S174  2020  5    
 6     0 Blue Jay               C1262     S174  2020  5    
 7     0 Brown Creeper          C1262     S174  2020  5    
 8     0 Brown-headed Cowbird   C1262     S174  2020  5    
 9     0 Carolina Wren          C1262     S174  2020  5    
10     0 Cedar Waxwing          C1262     S174  2020  5    
# … with 262,030 more rows
```

```
'data.frame':   262040 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ count    : num  0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ species  : chr  "American Crow" "American Goldfinch" "American Robin" "American Tree Sparrow" ...
 $ checklist: Factor w/ 6551 levels "C0001","C0002",..: 1262 1262 1262 1262 1262 1262 1262 1262 1262 1262 ...
 $ site     : Factor w/ 272 levels "S001","S002",..: 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 174 ...
 $ year     : Factor w/ 33 levels "1989","1990",..: 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 ...
 $ week     : Factor w/ 21 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
```

---

### Follow-up tests (from comments)

#### Fixed effect tests

**1)** Limiting to the 5 most abundant species, I get convergence warning 10.

```
# Model: count ~ species*year, ziformula = ~species

Warning message:
In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; iteration limit reached without convergence (10). See vignette('troubleshooting')
```

**2)** Limiting to top 10 most abundant species, I get convergence warning 9.

```
# Model: count ~ species*year, ziformula = ~species

Warning message:
In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; function evaluation limit reached without convergence (9). See vignette('troubleshooting')
```

**3)** Limiting to the top 2 most abundant species: The model appears to run without issue if the ziformula is just `~1` (`count ~ species*year, ziformula = ~1`). But, if I extend it to include the top 5 or the 10 most abundant species, it gives me convergence warning (9), and if I include all 40 species, it crashes R entirely.

**4)** Using just data from the top 2 most abundant species: if I include the week term, too (because species migrate over the 21 weeks), then I get a warning about the Hessian and also convergence warning (9):

```
# Model: count ~ species*week*year, ziformula = ~ 1

Warning messages:
1: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; non-positive-definite Hessian matrix. See vignette('troubleshooting')
2: In fitTMB(TMBStruc) :
  Model convergence problem; function evaluation limit reached without convergence (9). See vignette('troubleshooting')
```

#### Random effect tests

**1)** Contrarily, if I use random effects (see model below), then I *can* include species in the ziformula as a random effect and the model runs without errors.

```
count ~ (species|year), ziformula = ~ (1|species)
```

So, it seems like random effects might be the only option? However, I’m not quite sure which random effects coding is justifiable for species-by-year. It seems to me that species should only be crossed with year, but besides `(species|year)`, I don’t see any other way to produce separate species-by-year estimates without using a nested structure, which does not reflect reality given my understanding of what nested means (vs crossed). Is that the case?

**2)** Another note: Limiting to the top 10 species, if I use: `count ~ species + (species|year)`, then the model allows a fixed species effect for zero-inflation: `ziformula: ~species`. (I'm currently running this for all 40 species, but it's taking a while.)

Comment: Hi G., welcome to stack overflow, can you post the data using dput()? That helps us reproduce and understand the problems you have encountered

Comment: The data are pretty big (262K observations) ... I would like more information on how glmmTMB crashes - what are the exact symptoms?

Comment: @SushiChef - Thanks, I just added the data to my post via a google drive link. If there is a preferred method, I'll make the change!

Comment: @BenBolker - Thanks. I'll re-run that model and will post the exact error when it finishes. Sometimes it crashes R entirely, not leaving an error message. I do remember that it directed me to the "troubleshooting with glmmTMB" page. I also remember it would give me a number, I think `(8)` or `(9)`. Is that helpful?

Comment: (8) probably means a "false convergence" warning from nlminb, which is a hard one to troubleshoot ...

Comment: @BenBolker – I just updated my original post with the section "Follow-up tests", which have more information on what happens when I use only interaction terms of fixed effects for species-by-year. I hope that's helpful! Looking forward to hearing if you have any ideas. Thank you!